# Redirecting IP to AWS results in NGINX landing page

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, redirect, nginx, ip

I have a portfolio site hosted on AWS. When I first deployed the site to AWS, a site built in Ruby, I installed NGINX on the AWS instance. I went to register.com and redirected the IP address of my domain to point to the public IP address of the AWS instance. Everything was working fine. The site could be accessed with the AWS IP address or the domain name.

Things were fine until AWS retired the server my instance was on. I created a new instance and a new .pem key and deployed to the new instance. I repointed my domain the new AWS instance IP address. I can access the site without issue when using the IP address, 54.173.8.232. If I try and access it through the domain, http://www.williamjpalmer.com, I get the Welcome to NGINX landing page.I have deleted the previous instance thinking that maybe it was preventing the site from loading. I do not know very much about setting up servers and how to resolve issues like this. I would appreciate any help on this. It is frustrating that it worked the first time but now will not.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Double-check your `nginx.conf` file. I sure your nginx's setting have some problems

Comment: Did you check the server's log files?

Comment: As @BTuan already pointed out, this is probably a problem with your `nginx.conf`. Either try having another look at it yourself, or post the relevant parts of that file (removing any sensible information if necessary)

Comment: I have looked at my nginx.conf file and the only line that I changed was the include

Comment: include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

Comment: http {
passenger_root /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/passenger-5.1.8;
passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/wrappers/ruby;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;